# Running unit tests on a non OOP code without any return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, testing, python-unittest

I have a script of this form which is called in a program (from another similar function). I need to use unittest module to write tests for this function.

- It doesn't exactly return anything but changes a lot of globals
- It takes inputs
- I can't change it to an OOP code right now
- I want to test cases where I change a certain global varible and see if  ,let's say, TOTFRAC is positive or something. 
  I have read tests for OOP codes where I call each variable as an object parameter, but what do I do if my code isn't Object Oriented.

Note: I have removed a lot of lines of code because it is rather long, so things might not exactl make sense

```
import numpy
import math
def SETUP(LAST):
    def GOTO999():
        print(' ERROR IN GAS INPUT : NGAS=',NGAS,'\n')
        for J in range(1,6):
            # print(J)
            print(' N=',J,' NGAS=',NGASN[J],' FRAC=',FRAC[J])
        LAST=1                                                            
        return
    # A lot of globals
    # Initialising variables 
    NBREM=[]
    EBRTOT=[]
    for K in range(1,6):
        NBREM.append(0)
        EBRTOT.append(0.0)


    NGAS=int(input('NGAS'))
    NEVENT=int(input('NEVENT'))
    IMIP=int(input('IMIP'))
    NDVEC=int(input('NDVEC'))
    NSEED=int(input('NSEED'))
    ESTART=float(input('ESTART'))
    ETHRM=float(input('ETHRM'))
    ECUT=float(input('ECUT'))
    ICOUNT=0
    if(IMIP == 1):
        ICOUNT=1 
    if(NGAS == 0):
        LAST=1
        return  
    if(ESTART > 3.0*(10**6) and IMIP == 3):
        print(' SUBROUTINE STOPPED: X-RAY ENERGY=','%.3f' % ESTART,'EV. MAXIMUM ENERGY 3.0MEV')
        sys.exit() 

    if(IMIP != 1 and NEVENT > 10000):
        print(' SUBROUTINE STOPPED: NUMBER OF EVENTS =',NEVENT,' LARGER THAN ARRAY LIMIT OF 10000')
        sys.exit()


    NGASN=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        NGASN.append(int(input('NGASN'+str(i))))

    FRAC=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        FRAC.append(round(float(input('FRAC')),4))               
    TEMPC=round(float(input('TEMPC')),4)                         
    TORR=round(float(input('TORR')),4)                           


    # more inputs 
    if(IWRITE != 0):
        outputfile=open("DEGRAD.OUT","w")
    EBIG=0.05*ESTART/1000. 
    EFINAL=ESTART*1.0001+760.0*EBIG/TORR*(TEMPC+ABZERO)/293.15*EFIELD
    if(EFINAL < (1.01*ESTART)):
        EFINAL=1.01*ESTART 
    #   CHECK INPUT
    TOTFRAC=0.00
    if(NGAS == 0 or NGAS > 6):
            GOTO999()
    for J in range(1,NGAS):
        print('J',J)
        if(NGASN[J]== 0 or FRAC[J] == 0.00):
            GOTO999()
        TOTFRAC=TOTFRAC+FRAC[J]

    if(abs(TOTFRAC-100.00)> 1*(10**-6)):
        print(TOTFRAC)
        GOTO999()
    if(NDVEC): #22594
        PHI=0
        THETA=0
    elif(NDVEC==-1):
        PHI=0
        THETA=numpy.arccos(-1)
    elif(NDVEC==0):
        PHI=0.0
        THETA=API/2.0
    elif(NDVEC==2):
        R3=DRAND48(0.0,1.0)
        PHI=TWOPI*R3
        R4=DRAND48(1.5, 1.9)
        THETA=numpy.arccos(1.0-2.0*R4)
    else :
        print('DIRECTION OF BEAM NOT DEFINED NDVEC =',NDVEC)
        sys.exit()

    if(NSEED != 0):
        RM48(NSEED,0,0)                           
    CORR=ABZERO*TORR/(ATMOS*(ABZERO+TEMPC)*100.00)                    


    GOTO999()                                                            
    # end
```

Comment: You need to refactor the code, right now it's not testable besides of calling `SETUP` with different values of `LAST` and capturing the print statements. You can't test for `TOTFRAC` values because it's an local variable declared in `SETUP` function. Move the code that calculates `TOTFRAC` in a separate function `calculate_totfrac(ngas, frac)`, then you can write tests for it. Call the function inside `SETUP` where you calculate `TOTFRAC` right now. And so on.

Comment: The code looks as if has been automatically converted from some other programming language, like, Fortran, or so.

Answer (score 1):

As @hoefling has pointed out, the code as it is now is hardly testable.  But, this is not because it is not object oriented.  You can easily test non-object oriented code as long as it has a suitable structure.  Which means, break long functions down into smaller ones, use function arguments and return values rather than global variables etc. - none of this has anything to do with OOP.  In fact, your code violates many coding principles that were known and formulated long before OOP was en vogue (1974), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style.

I recommend reading one or some of the following books:

- Code Complete by Steve McConnell - a classic book about how to write great code.
- Refactoring by Martin Fowler - how to migrate from not-so-great code to better code.
- Clean Code by Robert C. Martin - again, how to write great code.